# Android set image to Landscape

Tags: android, accelerometer, landscape

I have an application which is running only on Portrait mode. Within that application there is Only image in which i want to have my accelerometer effect(rest of the screens should not be effected with accelerometer).

Can i have an idea of how should i perform the same task.

A help on this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: are you showing this image using a separate activity?

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in your each activity declaration in your `AndroidManifest` File **except the one** in which you are **displaying the image**.
and if you wish to show image only in LandScape then give `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` for that activity in Manifest File.